# Search results on different fields with LIKE

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I have 2 tables on my database (until now), one to store artists names and another to store songs (name and lyrics), but I need to use one `SELECT` to search inside of the artist name, song name and lyrics at once, but I'm getting a partial result and a lot of 1292 errors.

*Song table (songs)*

```
song_id
artist_id
song_name VARCHAR
song_lyric TEXT
```

*Artist table (artists)*

```
artist_id
artist_name
```

My first SQL idea was a `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT s.song_name AS SONG, s.song_id AS ID FROM songs AS s
    LEFT JOIN artists AS a ON s.song_id = a.artist_id
    WHERE s.song_name OR s.song_lyric OR a.artist_name LIKE '%some value%'
```

The `SELECT` gives a result if I use a artist name (if I have a unique name), but if I try some regular expression like 'Sun', 'Son' I got a empty set of results.

Any help will be wellcome

Comment: `WHERE s.song_name LIKE '%some value%' OR s.song_lyric LIKE '%some value%' OR a.artist_name LIKE '%some value%'`

Comment: What is your expected output?. Why are you using `s.song_id = a.artist_id` in `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: I want the ID like a hidden field (in Lazarus) to create another search, and the song name based on artist name, song name or some lyrics.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.song_name AS SONG, s.song_id AS ID FROM songs AS s
LEFT JOIN artists AS a ON s.artist_id = a.artist_id
WHERE s.song_name LIKE '%some value%' OR s.song_lyric LIKE '%some value%' 
OR a.artist_name LIKE '%some value%'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
SELECT s.song_name AS SONG, s.song_id AS ID FROM songs AS s LEFT JOIN artists
    AS a ON s.artist_id = a.artist_id WHERE s.song_name LIKE '%some value%' OR
    s.song_lyric LIKE '%some value%' OR a.artist_name LIKE '%some value%'
```